# Exception Log Analysis Tools or Techniques

Tags: debugging, elmah, logfile-analysis

I'm logging Exceptions, and it would be nice if there were some tools or technique to perform some analysis of the Exception logs, can anyone recommend any?

I'm imagining something with some kind of heuristic analysis, but I could be dreaming.

Things I think would be useful for the analysis tool *or technique* to find:

- All exceptions of type X are on url A
- All exceptions of type Y are from user Agent B
- All exceptions of type Z are limited to 4pm on saturday ;-)

If you have any other tips or techniques to speeding up the analysis of Exception logs that would be good too.

Note: I'm using Elmah with SQLite (altho the data can be transported anywhere that makes it easier, eg SQL)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried [elmah-loganalyzer](http://code.google.com/p/elmah-loganalyzer/) here's what I found

- One or two of the reports are helpful,
- The querying capabilities are not flexible enough.(no group by etc)
- No Magic heuristic analyzer ;-)
- It does not read SQLite (I can transfer the data to SQL)
- does not remember SQL connection settings